# Using Qt macro Q_OBJECT for slots

Tags: c++, qt

This question is pretty sure will seem as duplicate, but after doing a research and looking at same questions I found that it is needed to use macro `Q_OBJECT` for `SLOT` using but when I use it I got a compilation error. Here are my code snippets.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "window_general.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 Window_General window_general;

 window_general.show();
 return app.exec();
}
```

**windows_general.h**

```
#ifndef WINDOW_GENERAL_H
#define WINDOW_GENERAL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

class QPushButton;
class Window_General : public QWidget
{

public:
  explicit Window_General(QWidget *parent = 0);


private slots:
  void MyhandleButton();

private:
 QPushButton *m_button;
};


#endif // WINDOW_GENERAL_H
```

**windows_general.cpp**

```
#include "window_general.h"
#include <QPushButton>


Window_General::Window_General(QWidget *parent) :
 QWidget(parent)
 {
 // Set size of the window
 setFixedSize(800, 500);
 // Create and position the button
 m_button = new QPushButton("Hello World", this);
 m_button->setGeometry(10, 10, 80, 30);

  connect(m_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (MyhandleButton()));
}

void Window_General::MyhandleButton()
{
 m_button->setText("Example");
 m_button->resize(100,100);
}
```

In this code I have a runtime error:

> `QObject::connect`: No such slot `QWidget::MyhandleButton()` in
>   ../prj/window_general.cpp:14

If I put a `Q_OBJECT` macro at here,

```
class Window_General : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Window_General(QWidget *parent = 0);


private slots:
  void MyhandleButton();

private:
 QPushButton *m_button;
};
```

I then have this error:

> D:\work\my_qt\prj\window_general.h:8: error: undefined reference to
>   `vtable` for `Window_General`

My question is, how I can use button event in this code set?

Comment: You're not showing how you *build* the files. The link error is probably caused by not running moc on the file.

Comment: Sometimes when a vtable error appears, a make distclean is enough to solve the issue. Qt tends to produce support files which doesn't update with some changes

Comment: The first error is definetely because you are missing Q_OBJECT at the beginning of Windows_General, you should put Q_OBJECT in both classes. Finally clean project and run qmake is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to call [qmake utility](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html) to regenerate moc. `Q_OBJECT` puts some QObject's overriding member functions declaration to your class, and qmake generates their definitions to yourclass.moc.cpp. Every time you place new `Q_OBJECT`, you need to call qmake.

Comment: Could you please add a code how to call qmake to make your answer more clear?

Comment: I have found `Run qmake` in Qt creator menu and that did the trick, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the `Q_OBJECT` macro altogether by using the pointer-to-member-function syntax instead of the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. For example:

```
connect(m_button, &QPushButton::released, this, &Window_General::MyhandleButton);
```