# Do I need to use the Q_OBJECT macro if I only use slots?

Tags: qt

I have a few classes that are using QWebSocket and it seems I am able to call connect to handle callbacks for connect, close, etc. My debugger says that all is working properly.

If I use the Q_OBJECT macro in my class, than I have to run the MOC compiler in my cmake, which is a pain in the ass when trying to create a lib from my classes and use it in another application, that will make a separate post about.

If I delete the Q_OBJECT macro everything seems to build and run fine without it. So, question is, do I really need it if I am just connecting QWebSocket's signals up to slots?

A related post is:
[Using Qt macro Q_OBJECT for slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908503/using-qt-macro-q-object-for-slots)
However, that is to tackle the error that results from not using the MOC compiler. I know how to do that, but I question whether I need Q_OBJECT in the first place.

Comment: Using `Q_OBJECT` is required if you use signals/slots in your class. I double it really works without the macro, unless you don't use signal connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Qt [QObject class reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details):

> Notice that the Q_OBJECT macro is mandatory for any object that implements signals, slots or properties.

Comment: Then why does it work without it when using slots, but not signals? Furthermore, why can I use a lambda as a slot in connect in Qt5? There seems to be some debate https://forum.qt.io/topic/115188/do-i-need-to-use-the-q_object-macro-if-i-only-use-slots/5

Comment: Feel free to enter the "undefined/unsupported" world ! I'm not maintaining your code :)